# PHP If statement doesn't append variable properly

Tags: php, mysql, variables, if-statement, while-loop

I am querying my database and dumping the data into an HTML table. One of my database keys is called "time_expire", with a value of -1 meaning never. Therefore, to show something to the effect of "never" in the HTML table instead of the raw data I am attempting to change the variable before it is echo'd.

This is my code

```
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM penalties ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            if ($rows['time_expire'] = '-1') {
                $rows['time_expire'] = '<span class="label label-important">Permanent</span>';
            }

            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td><a href="ban.php?banid=' . $rows['id'] . '">' . $rows['id'] . '</a></td>';
            echo "<td>" . $rows['client_id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['type'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . date('m/d/Y', $rows['time_add']) . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['duration'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['time_expire'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['reason'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
```

This code does not error, however every row in my HTML table has an expiration value of "never", even if the the raw data is different.

Comment: You probably wanted to write `==` not `=` there.

Comment: This makes my output as if the if statement doesn't exist, it ignores it. No error.

Comment: yes, sure. It's like that .. if ($rows['time_expire'] == '-1') {

Comment: put `var_dump($rows['time_expire']);` just before if statement to see what values your variable becomes

Comment: Nevermind, this was correct. I need a == on the if line, not the line below it as well. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a common typo in the if statemenet

```
if ($rows['time_expire'] = '-1') [
                         ^
                         |
```

If you want to the interpreter spot these for you, try using [yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions) like this:

```
if ('-1' = $rows['time_expire'])
```

This form will create error however the correct forms both work ok:

```
'-1' == $rows['time_expire']
```

or

```
$rows['time_expire'] == '-1'
```

Comment: Giving it a == on the 'if' line worked, I tried doing it on both lines before. Thanks, I cant up vote you though.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is supposed to be:

```
if ($rows['time_expire'] == '-1')
```

not

```
if ($rows['time_expire'] = '-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing If condition to   `if ($rows['time_expire'] == '-1')`. Right now what your condition says that variable `$rows['time_expire']` is equal to `'-1'` which is always returning true.It might get you in the unlimited looping.

Answer (score 0):

First what type is `time_expire`?

If `time_expire` is numeric then you should change the condition to:
`if ($rows['time_expire'] == -1)` which will evaluate properly.

Secondly your condition checking is actually assigning the value to `$rows['time_expire']` with single `=`, it should be double `=` like `==`.